# Services for networking: to use or not to use?

Tags: android, android-service

Basically, there is a Google way, which suggests using `Service` for long running operations (which I use at the time). On the other hand, there are a lot of examples in community by honored developers, which avoid using `Service` and at most incorporate `Fragment`'s `setRetainInstance(boolean retain)`.

While Google has declared that a lot of bad stuff might happen if we don't use a `Service`, I still feel anxious because there are, it seems, so many projects leaving `Service` aside.

Can you consolidate the Google's case or provide suggestions for abandoning `Service`?

P.S. I'm developing "classic" rest-client applications.
P.S.S. I forgot to mention that `Service` is used in pair with `ContentProvider`(for cachging purposes, guard against system app forceshutdowns).

Thanks.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using service , but service by default runs on main thread , you would have to make sure you run it on a separate background thread for network operations

Comment: If the IntentService/ContentProvider/CursorLoader pattern is the recommended way, then it would be nice to have an official implantation of a cursor adaper for the recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

If the network request is very likely to take under a second, or if you don't mind it if your process terminates before the request completes, using simple threading from the UI layer is fine, IMHO.

But once the user leaves your app (HOME, responds to an incoming call, etc.), the lifetime of your process is limited, and it could be *very* short if you do not have a service to tell the OS that you're still doing important work for the user.

So, if the network request is more in the 1-15 second range, and you'd like to feel fairly confident that the work will run to completion, use an `IntentService` or something along those lines.

If the network request is likely to be longer than that, such as a large download, now you have to worry about the device going to sleep and such. [My `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) was designed for this sort of scenario, where it will keep the device awake long enough to get the work done, then let the device go back asleep.

Some developers use services for all significant network I/O, skipping them only for truly ephemeral stuff like thumbnail images to populate a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. So long as the service is only running when it is actively delivering value to the user, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks. I asked about regular rest requests like: Observable<List<Item>> getPopularItems and similar. I guess, I don't want scenarios when request is sent twice due to app recreation coming from a phone call activity but at the same time what're the chances of that happening(recreation). I mean, is that still a viable scenario? How rare is it? Does it really worth writing a whole bunch of Service->ContentProvider(I use it for caching purposes) code?

Comment: @midnight: Since I have no idea how and under what circumstances you are doing this stuff, I cannot answer that. Usually, you only make REST calls to modify data based on positive user input (e.g., they click the "send" button), not just based on lifecycle events.